# How to get text inside one span tag to another span tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need to get the value `40.78` from `<span>` to be stored in `<span id ="test">`.

Tried the code below. But not able to figure out what's going wrong. The error  getting on console is :

> **Uncaught ReferenceError: div is not defined**.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```js
var span = div.getElementsByTagName("span");
var test = document.getElementById('test');
console.log(test.innerHTML = span.innerHTML);
```

```html
<span>40.78</span>
<span id="test"></span>
```

Comment: As the error says there's no variable `div` defined

Comment: @epascarello — The first line of JS in the code tries to use a variable called `div` which isn't defined!

Comment: Going to be a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method after they fix the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div` is not defined any where in the code. Use `document` instead.

`getElementsByTagName()` returns collection, you have to use index. I will also suggest you to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` when dealing with text only content:

```html
<html>
  <body>
   <div>
    <span>40.78</span>
   </div>
    <span id = "test"></span>
     <script>
      var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
      var test = document.getElementById( 'test' );
      test.textContent = span.textContent;
      console.log(test.textContent);
     </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it is not defined, and you don't define it anywhere.

If you want to use it, you need to define it.

e.g.

```
var div = document.querySelector('div');
```

---

Re edit.

The solution in the above answer doesn't apply to the *edited* code. It is no longer clear what you expect the `div` variable (which is still undeclared) to represent.